# How can I dynamically create arrays whose names are generated from source data?

Tags: arrays, perl

I am processing a C++ file. Initially I store the terminal results into an array using backticks. My terminal result is as below and it varies depending on the C file. In this case I have only 3 `TAP` prefixes: `TAP1`, `TAP2`, and `TAP3`. For some C++ files the `TAP` count might be more than 10 (it's non-deterministic).

```
TAP1= 0
TAP1= 0
TAP1= 0
TAP2= 0
TAP1= 0
TAP3= 0
TAP1= 0
TAP1= 0
TAP2= 0
TAP1= 144
TAP1= 1300
TAP3= 2795
TAP1= 2963
TAP1= 3031
TAP2= 3291
TAP3= 16395
TAP1= 16699
TAP1= 16711
TAP2= 71
TAP1= 36
TAP2= 2994
TAP1= 6634
TAP2= 6769
TAP1= 6837
TAP1= 7233
TAP2= 10985
TAP1= 1103
```

For the above case my array is `@tap = (TAP1, TAP2, TAP3)`. This is automatically stored as follows:

```
my @store_taps;

foreach my $a (@lines) {
    if ($a =~ m/(.*)=(.*)/g) {
        push(@store_taps, $1);
    }
}
```

My question is how to declare an array for each `TAP` and store the respective values automatically. `@TAP1 = (0, 0, 0, 144, 1300, ...)`, `@TAP2 = (0, 0, 3291, 71, ...)` and `@TAP3 = (0, 0, 2795, ...)`. I don't know how to automatically generate these arrays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably want a hash where the keys are `TAPn` and the values are array references.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split/\s*=\s*/;
    push(@{$data{$key}}, $val);
}

print Dumper(\%data);

__DATA__
TAP1= 0
TAP1= 0
TAP1= 0
TAP2= 0
TAP1= 0
TAP3= 0
TAP1= 0
TAP1= 0
TAP2= 0
TAP1= 144
TAP1= 1300
TAP3= 2795
TAP1= 2963
TAP1= 3031
TAP2= 3291
TAP3= 16395
TAP1= 16699
TAP1= 16711
TAP2= 71
TAP1= 36
TAP2= 2994
TAP1= 6634
TAP2= 6769
TAP1= 6837
TAP1= 7233
TAP2= 10985
TAP1= 1103
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'TAP2' => [
                      '0',
                      '0',
                      '3291',
                      '71',
                      '2994',
                      '6769',
                      '10985'
                    ],
          'TAP3' => [
                      '0',
                      '2795',
                      '16395'
                    ],
          'TAP1' => [
                      '0',
                      '0',
                      '0',
                      '0',
                      '0',
                      '0',
                      '144',
                      '1300',
                      '2963',
                      '3031',
                      '16699',
                      '16711',
                      '36',
                      '6634',
                      '6837',
                      '7233',
                      '1103'
                    ]

    };
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Matt Jacob. I have one more continued question. How do I actually compare the two hashes you have generated? After storing these values in hashes, I will  change the testcases and run the program one more time. This time it will generate the same number of outputs(Taps) but with some same and different output values. I need to store the unique outputs generated at the second time.

Comment: @nandeeshv That sounds like something that deserves a separate question, but there are many good modules available that can help, e.g., [Data::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Compare).

Comment: Thanks for the link @Matt Jacob

Answer (score 0):

No, you need hashes.

`my %tap_for;
for my $l (@lines)
{
  chomp $l; # if you haven't already
  my ($tap, $val) = split /=/, $l, 2;
  push @{$tap_for{$tap}}, $val;
}`

You can do this all in a single pass.  Much simpler than the method you were looking for, and you don't have to create arbitrary variables whose names you'll need to dynamically look for.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tanktalus

Comment: I have one more continued question. How do I actually compare the two hashes you have generated? After storing these values in hashes, I will compile change the testcases and run the program one more time. This time it will generate the same number of outputs(Taps) but with some same and different output values. I need to store the unique outputs generated at the second time.